# File Saving In Folder In Wpf

Tags: wpf

i am storing a  pdf file to c:\program files... through wpf (exe Installation) it is not allowing me to save that file due to Administrator permission,
But When i am storing same into D:\ drive it is working fine

Can any One give me the solution For it

Answer (score 0):

The Program files directory requires adminstrative rights to be written in. This has nothing to do with WPF but is simply how Windows operates. Either you start your application as an Administrator or you get your application to show the UAC window to escalate privileges.